# string concat replacing second string arg too, possible es6 issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing code to create a chess board in es6 for a nodejs project

```js
const XPOSITIONS = [{
                    "name": 'a',
                    "index": 0
                        },
                    {
                    "name": 'b',
                    "index": 1
                        },
                    {
                    "name": 'c',
                    "index": 2
                        },
                    {
                    "name": 'd',
                    "index": 3
                        },
                    {
                    "name": 'e',
                    "index": 4
                        },
                    {
                    "name": 'f',
                    "index": 5
                        },
                    {
                    "name": 'g',
                    "index": 6
                        },
                    {
                    "name": 'h',
                    "index": 7
                        }
                    ];
const YPOSITIONS = [{
                    "name": '1',
                    "index": 1
                        },
                    {
                    "name": '2',
                    "index": 2
                        },
                    {
                    "name": '3',
                    "index": 3
                        },
                    {
                    "name": '4',
                    "index": 4
                        },
                    {
                    "name": '5',
                    "index": 5
                        },
                    {
                    "name": '6',
                    "index": 6
                        },
                    {
                    "name": '7',
                    "index": 7
                        },
                    {
                    "name": '8',
                    "index": 8
                        }
                    ];

function makeboard() {
    "use strict";

    var boardArray = Array(...Array(...XPOSITIONS)).map(() => Array(...YPOSITIONS));
  
    XPOSITIONS.forEach(function(x, xindex, xarray) {
        // console.log("x" + xindex);
      
        YPOSITIONS.forEach(function(y, yindex, yarray) {
            // console.log("y" + yindex);
            // console.log("x check" + xindex, x.index);

            boardArray[xindex][yindex].name = x.name.concat(y.name);
            console.log("xindex " + xindex, "yindex " + yindex, "xname " + x.name, "yname " + y.name, boardArray[xindex][yindex].name);
            boardArray[xindex][yindex].xindex = x.index;
            boardArray[xindex][yindex].yindex = y.index;
        });
        // console.log(boardArray);
    });
    return boardArray;
}

var board = makeboard();
```

. I have **const** (constants) for edges name like this

```
const XPOSITIONS = [{
                "name": 'a',
                "index": 0
                    },...
const YPOSITIONS = [{
                "name": '1',
                "index": 1
                    },...
```

I have mapped them to create a 8X8 2d array

```
var boardArray = Array(...Array(...XPOSITIONS)).map(() => Array(...YPOSITIONS));
```

Then I try to assign each square in this 2d array it's name in forEach loop

```
XPOSITIONS.forEach(function(x, xindex, xarray) {
    YPOSITIONS.forEach(function(y, yindex, yarray) {

        boardArray[xindex][yindex].name = x.name.concat(y.name);

    });
```

But the problem is after each board square name assignment `y.name` also changes like so does the square name

```
yname a1
yname a2
yname a3
yname a4
yname a5
yname a6
yname a7
yname a8
yname ba1
yname ba2
yname ba3
yname ba4
yname ba5
yname ba6
yname ba7
yname ba8
yname cba1
yname cba2
yname cba3
yname cba4
yname cba5
yname cba6
yname cba7
yname cba8
yname dcba1 
yname dcba2 
yname dcba3 
yname dcba4 
yname dcba5 
yname dcba6 
yname dcba7 
yname dcba8 
yname edcba1...
```

What could be the issue, or what am I doing wrong. Please help I am new to es6 and also not very great with javascript.

**See code snippet in developer console**

Comment: Seems like there's some general misunderstanding/over-specification here; example; `const XPOSITIONS= 'abcdefgh'.split('');` replaces your first 16 lines of code and contains equal representation. `YPOSITIONS` is even simpler. Also, don't pigeonhole yourself into thinking that a 2-dimensional array is the only data abstraction for a 2-dimensional chess board. There are many alternative ways to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the same object references as the contents of all of the arrays. This is why you see the original objects being modified, which creates a snowball effect when you concatenate the objects' `.name` in the loops.

Specifically, this line:

```
var boardArray = Array(...Array(...XPOSITIONS)).map(() => Array(...YPOSITIONS));
```

is equivalent to:

```
var y1 = { name: '1', index: 1 };
var y2 = { name: '2', index: 2 };
var y3 = { name: '3', index: 3 };
var y4 = { name: '4', index: 4 };
var y5 = { name: '5', index: 5 };
var y6 = { name: '6', index: 6 };
var y7 = { name: '7', index: 7 };
var y8 = { name: '8', index: 8 };
var boardArray = [
  [ y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8],
  [ y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8],
  [ y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8],
  [ y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8],
  [ y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8],
  [ y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8],
  [ y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8],
  [ y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8]
];
```

As you can see the *same objects* are being used in each row. That means when you do:

```
boardArray[xindex][yindex].name = x.name.concat(y.name);
```

you're changing the `.name` for that object in every column. So when you change `boardArray[0][0].name`, you're also changing `boardArray[1][0].name`, `boardArray[2][0].name`, `boardArray[3][0].name`, etc. You can verify this is the case by adding a `console.dir(boardArray)` right before you return from your function and you will see that the contents are all exactly the same.

Also, `const` does not mean that the properties on the object won't change, it just means an *assignment* to that *variable* only happens once.

Comment: I believe there is something wrong with assignment `boardArray[xindex][yindex].name = x.name.concat(y.name);` because when I comment that line out and just console `console.log(x.name.concat(y.name));` the result is as I want but that assignment does something which I am not able to understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I figured that out after carefully reading your last answers, Thanks!